# How does MS Windows purge MSMQ

Tags: c#, .net, windows, msmq

I have **multiple instances of the same app working with** `MSMQ`.

So I use code like this

```
MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\MyApp" + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
```

But each time app starts it is gonna create new `MSMQ`.

Will MS Windows keep old `MSMQ`  for ever or they will be deleted automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you create the queue it remains on that system. They are never automatically deleted. If you're just creating it for temporary or testing purposes and you need to remove it you can call

```
MessageQueue.Delete([your queue path]);
```

Sometimes I've done that when unit testing.

Comment: Do you know how to how to delete selected messages MSMQ but not all of them?

Comment: You could read each message from the queue. Inspect each message as you read it. If you want to keep it, put it in another queue. (If you don't just discard it.)  When you're done, read the messages from the second queue and put them back in the first queue.